# $observe function never gets called in my tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs

We have a directive that has an optional attribute on it. If the attribute is not there, it provides a default value. The attribute is usually set from data in the scope (i.e., the value of the attribute is usually an expression and not a literal string. See http://jsfiddle.net/8PGZ4/

As such, we are using `attrs.$observe` in the directive to set up the scope properly. This works great in the app itself. However, when trying to test this (using Jasmine), the function in the `$observe` never gets run. Our test looks something like this:

```
describe("myDirective", function(){ 
    function getDirectiveScope(compile, rootScope, directiveHTML)
    {
        return (compile(directiveHTML)(rootScope)).scope();
    }

    describe("foo", function () {
        it("should return the default value", inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
            var directiveScope = getDirectiveScope($compile, $rootScope, '<div my-directive></div>');
            expect(directiveScope.bar).toBe("No Value");
        }));
        it("should now return the value given", inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
            $rootScope.foo = "asdf";
            var directiveScope = getDirectiveScope($compile, $rootScope, '<div my-directive foo="{{foo}}"></div>');
            expect(directiveScope.bar).toBe("asdf");
        }));
    });
});
```

These then fail with the following errors:

```
Expected undefined to be 'No Value'.
Expected undefined to be 'asdf'.
```

I put a console.log in the `$observe` function to try to see what was going on, and when the tests run, I never see the log. Is there an explicit call I have to make for the `$observe` to run? Is there something else going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to trigger a digest cycle to let the AngularJS magic happen in your test. Try:

```
it("should return the default value", inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
  var directiveScope = getDirectiveScope($compile, $rootScope, '<div my-directive></div>');
  $rootScope.$digest();
  expect(directiveScope.bar).toBe("No Value");
}));
```